# Slider Revolution, reducing left margin/padding on mobile

Tags: css, wordpress, slider, themes, fuse

Checked everywhere and tried a lot of different things, still nothing works.

Site is www.livehealthyacademy.com

I am trying to get rid of left margin/padding on mobile for my slider revolution. I want the slider to span the entire width. Any CSS that will help me out with this? I've tried these different lines below, tried some others as well. Not familiar with this type of CSS so Im simply copy and pasting what others have said works for them.

```
.entry-content .rev_slider ul {padding-left: 0 !important; margin-left: 0 !important}

.entry .rev_slider ul {padding-left: 0 !important; margin-left: 0 !important}

.content .rev_slider ul {padding-left: 0 !important; margin-left: 0 !important}

#content .rev_slider ul {padding-left: 0 !important; margin-left: 0 !important}

.rev_slider ul {padding-left: 0 !important; margin-left: 0 !important}

#sliders-container {
margin: 0 20px !important}
```

Thanks

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMUst.png): [View custom class here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMUst.png)

Comment: You're going to have to share a link or code and a screenshot

Comment: Sorry, thought I put the link in. Link is www.livehealthyacademy.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the div that's the main container for the row. The class "col-sm-12" adds padding to elements within it. I usually have a "no-mobile-padding" css rule and then add it where I don't want padding.

Add this:

```
div#column-1cd465cfdcf85c93601bd492fa0a9e36 {
padding: 0;
```

}

Hope it helps bud

[image: highlighted element]

Comment: You my friend, are a good man. It works! You have provided a solution no one else has haha. Thanks!

Comment: @Brandon you're welcome! Always remember that if there's space, it's usually a margin on the element itself, padding on a containing element, its position is fixed and has a "top", "left" etc value or it's a float issue

Comment: Hey @daniel, I'm now having issues with the margin coming back for tablet. It seems to only appear between 768px width and 1200px width. Any idea how I should handle this? The homepage seems fine but my other pages are not. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm also having some issues with the contact page. The column seems to be changing after every refresh.

Comment: @Brandon I don't see a banner on the homepage at all, can you confirm it's working?

Comment: As for the contact issue, it might be best to add another question with detail for that particular issue, I'll be happy to assist you @Brandon

Comment: I can confirm the homepage is working on all devices. Are the other banners working for you?

Comment: Also, here is the link to the contact page question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42371692/slider-revolution-header-column-changing-on-refresh

Comment: Ok, the banners are back now. I cannot reproduce the white space issue, do you have an image? What browser are you using?

Comment: I do have an image, how can I upload it? Are you viewing the page in tablet size? The white space is gone on mobile but not on tablet.

Comment: I uploaded the image above in the description.

Comment: Try this :

section#section-58ac6402158aa .fw-container {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

Comment: No luck on this. It seems to have shrunk the padding issue by a little bit but white space is still there.

Comment: It appears that the section id changes upon every refresh. Even is I set the section ID in my page builder.

Comment: Did you set your own id? Can you set a class instead?

Comment: I can add a class, what is the class I should add?

Comment: Added an image of the page builder to the description

Comment: So you can name it anything, perhaps "no-spaces" would be useful. Then you use the following .no-spaces .fw-container {     margin: 0;     padding: 0; } also, it must not be on the slide but where you're putting the slide show.

Comment: Doesn't appear to work as of now. It could be an issue with the class within the page builder.

Comment: Did you put "no-spaces" in the class for the section that has the slide show in it?

Comment: Yes I posted a screenshot of where I put it above.