# Slider Revolution- Header column changing on refresh

Tags: css, wordpress, header, slider, styles

I'm trying to remove the padding from my slider revolution header, however the column id seems to be changing after every refresh. The style I am using to remove the padding is

```
div#column-28eac7eab21857970fc76a0201ab0fe2 {
padding: 0;
```

I cannot get it to change due to the id changing on refresh. Any ideas on how this is happening?

Thanks
[Image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gajEu.png)

[Page builder can be seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXwtz.png)

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the padding you'd like to remove and the page that it should be removed from?

Comment: Posted above in the description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An ID is supposed to be unique to each element and so if the banner on one page has an ID of "1234" if the same banner is on another page, the ID should be the same. If there happens to be a banner on another page but is a different banner i.e. has different images, it should have its own ID.

Can you try the css below on your site?

```
section#section-58ac615d427d3 .fw-container {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Because the padding is on the "fw-container" class and not the section that has an ID, we call the ID followed by a space and then the class of the element that we want to edit which is "fw-container" this way the rule will only apply to elements with a class of "fw-container" that are inside the element with the id of "section-58ac615d427d3"

Comment: Hey Daniel, added this in, still not seeing any changes to the margin or padding.

Comment: It appears that the section ID is changing upon every refresh as well. What is odd is this is not happening on any other page that I have.

Comment: Assuming your site uses a page-builder, do you have an option to add an ID or class to the section that the slideshow is in?

Comment: Yes I do, should I add the section ID or the column ID?

Comment: I added the section ID but nothing changed. I've posted a picture in the description of what my page builder looks like.

Comment: This is the slideshow control. So go to the Wordpress "Page" that the slide show is on. That page either uses a short code "[slider name]" for the slideshow or a page builder like visual-composer to create page layouts with a drag and drop like interface.

Comment: Ahh I see. I have the unyson page builder installed.

Comment: Great! We're on the same page now :) on one of the pages, there's usually a "container" or "section" that the slideshow is in, the container should allow you to add a class to it. Enter "no-spaces" in that field. Then use the css `.no-spaces .fw-container {margin:0;padding:0;}`

Comment: This works! Thanks again for all your help and sticking with me! Learning a lot! Thanks again!

Comment: Awesome! Perseverance will get you far! Glad to help